# Date formate error character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Tags: r

JAN-15" to a POSIxct

```
as.POSIXct(c("5-JAN-15"),tz="GMT")
```

I am getting this error

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: without telling it, R has no way of knowing whether 5 or 15 is the year/month.

Comment: You need to add `format="%d-%b-%y"` to `as.POSIXct`.

Comment: Which you could have seen quite quickly from [googling your error](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#es_th=1&q=character%20string%20is%20not%20in%20a%20standard%20unambiguous%20format)

Answer (score 1):

The format must be specified.

```
as.POSIXct("5-JAN-15", format="%d-%h-%y", tz="GMT")
#[1] "2015-01-05 GMT"
```